# Async function in React doesn't await

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a contact form component. There is an async handleSend function that works properly. Then I added an additional asynchronous function call inside it (postalCodesDistance).

```
    async handleSend() {
        this.setState({isSending:true})
        const mailerPath = this.context.path+'mail.php';
        let dane = {}

      this.postalCodesDistance(this.context.companyCoords,this.state.customerCoords).then(distance=>{
            if(distance!==undefined){
                dane.distance = distance
            }
        })

        const form = await axios.post( mailerPath, dane).then(res => {
            this.setState({sendingError: false, isSending: false})
        }).catch(err => { 
            console.log(err) 
            this.setState({sendingError: true, isSending: false})
        })
    };
```

```
    async postalCodesDistance(postalCodeA, postalCodeB){
        try{
            const countryA = this.checkPostalCode(postalCodeA)
            const countryB = this.checkPostalCode(postalCodeB)
            if( !countryA || !countryB){
                return console.log("At least one of the arguments is not valid")
            } 
            const postalCodeA_radians = await this.findCoords(postalCodeA,countryA)
            const postalCodeB_radians = await this.findCoords(postalCodeB,countryB)
            return this.calculateCoordsDistance(postalCodeA_radians,postalCodeB_radians)
        }catch(err){
            console.log("At least on of the given postal codes couldn't be found",err)
        }
    }
```

The issue I have is that the function is not awaiting for findCoords result (another async function) and I always get undefined postalCodeA_radians and postalCodeB_radians values.

checkPostalCode is not an asynchronous function. It is just checking some regular expression. In findCoords function there is an axios get request like:

```
 async findCoords(postalCode,country){
    ... // some code with defining Url
    return await axios.get(Url)
        .then(data=>{
            if(data.data!==undefined){
                if(data.data[0].display_name.includes(country)){
                    return [data.data[0].lat*(Math.PI/180), data.data[0].lon*Math.PI/180]
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
}
```

As I prepared those functions using simple node they were working correctly. I'm getting an issue when I try to put them in my ContactForm class component in React application. Firstly I thought it is a problem with component lifecycle, but I made a button below the form with onClick={this.onContinue}

```
     async onContinue(){
        const send = await this.handleSend()
    }
```

and it's still not working properly.

Comment: Can you post the code for `this.findCoords`? It's tough to help without seeing that function.

Comment: You aren't awaiting the `this.postalCodesDistance()` call.

Comment: What is the code for `this.checkPostalCode`? Is it async as well? Do you need to `await` those function calls so that `countryA` and `countryB` won't be `undefined` when you hit the `this.findCoords` calls?